# how to right justify with $ character

Tags: string, scala, interpolation

I'm trying to right justify a value (float) with dollar sign. But I'm justifying the value not the dollar sign. So how can I justify the dollar sign as well.

```
println(f"$$${10.5340}%40.2f")
$                                   10.53
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

1. Format the number with two digits and a dollar sign
2. Format the resulting string such that it's aligned to the right with total width of 43 (40 + 1 + 2) characters

Something like that:

```
println(f"${f"$$${10.5340}%.2f"}%43s")
```

Result (total width independent of the number `10.5340`):

```
                                     $10.53
```

Example with many different numbers:

```
for (n <- List(1234.567, 0.33, 1.0, 42.0, 45.2)) {
  println(f"${f"$$${n}%.2f"}%43s")
}
```

Results in:

```
                                   $1234.57
                                      $0.33
                                      $1.00
                                     $42.00
                                     $45.20
```

I hope it's a joke application - you aren't really counting real money using `double`s, are you?

Comment: Thanks, I'm just practicing

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using string interpolation on [java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance):

```
import java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance

val amount1 = f"${getCurrencyInstance.format(10.5340)}%40s"
val amount2 = f"${getCurrencyInstance.format(100.5340)}%40s"
val amount3 = f"${getCurrencyInstance.format(1000.5340)}%40s"

// amount1: String = "                                  $10.53"
// amount2: String = "                                 $100.53"
// amount3: String = "                               $1,000.53"
```

In case it's the currency for a different country, say, France:

```
import java.util.{Currency, Locale}

val currInstance = getCurrencyInstance

currInstance.setCurrency( Currency.getInstance(new Locale("fr", "FR")) )

val amount4 = f"${currInstance.format(123.456)}%40s"
// amount4: String = "                               EUR123.46"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's important that decimal places would align for any number (i.e. padding so that decimal dot is 40 characters from the left, and not padding with 40 characters regardless of number of digits), I can't see how this can be done directly with Scala's formatter - but it can be achieved with the help of Java's `DecimalFormat`:

```
scala> import java.text._;
import java.text._

scala> println(f"${new DecimalFormat("$###.##").format(10.5340)}%40s")
                              $10.53

scala> println(f"${new DecimalFormat("$###.##").format(1000.5340)}%40s")
                            $1000.53
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
println(f"${"$"}%40s${10.5340}%.2f")
```

Output :

> $10.53

Comment: but this would always add 40 spaces, even if the number has more digits - so decimal digits won't align (e.g. if you have 10.534 and 100.534)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
printf("%40c%.2f%n", '$', 10.5340)
```

Comment: That looks strange, because the dots aren't vertically aligned. Try it out with `for (n <- List(1234.567, 0.33, 1.0, 42.0, 45.2)) {
   printf("%40c%.2f%n", '$', n)
 }`